# Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int

Tags: java, android, firebase

I think I have found a bug in Firebase or in Android Studio.
I added code (fig1) to ChatActivity.java, and I get an error:

> ( **com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int**)

But when I remove the code (fig1), I still receive the message in every script that contains (fig2).
Why is it now referring it to an integer instead of a string after removing it?

fig1 (code)

```
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myConnectionsRef;
...

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...`        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myConnectionsRef = database.getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/n_newmessages_c");` fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (input.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Please enter some texts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {....                    myConnectionsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        try{
                            notifMcount = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: NOTIFICATION COUNT MESSAGES--------------------- = " + notifMcount );
                            long newNotifAmount = notifMcount + 1;
                            myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                                    .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                                    .child("n_newmessages_c")
                                    .setValue(newNotifAmount);

                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: NullPointerException" + e.getMessage() );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

fig2 (code) (from MessengerFriendsOnline.java)

```
    private void updateUserslist(){
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUsersList: updating users list");

    mAdapter = new MessagesListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_friend_listitem, mUserList);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected user: " + mUserList.get(position).toString());

            //navigate to profile activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_user), mUserList.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void updateFriendsList(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getPhotos: getting Friend(s)");
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    for(int i = 0; i < mFriends.size(); i++){
        final int count = i;
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                .equalTo(mFriends.get(i));
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    //boolean is_Online = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).isOnline();
                   // Log.w(TAG, "onDataChange: FRIEND IS ONLINE ********************** = " + is_Online );
                    //if(is_Online == true) {
                        mUserList.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                    //}
                }
                if(count >= mFriends.size() - 1){
                    updateUserslist();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}


private void getFriends(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getFollowing: searching for FRIENDS **************************************");
    mFriends.clear();
    mUserList.clear();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_friends))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found friend----------------**: " + singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).toString());

                mFriends.add(singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue().toString());

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Freinds user id: " + mFriends.toString()  );
            }
            //get the photos
            updateFriendsList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

ChatActivity.java

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "ChatActivity";

private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
private ListView listView;
private String loggedInUserName = "";
private int messagesCount = 0;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private long notifMcount;
Map data;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myConnectionsRef;

private User mUser;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    //find views by Ids
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    data = new HashMap();

    try {
        mUser = getUserFromBundle();
        //init();
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        // Start sign in/sign up activity
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // User is already signed in, show list of messages
        showAllOldMessages();
    }
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myConnectionsRef = database.getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/n_newmessages_c");
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: USER SELECT TO CHAT WITH********************** " + mUser.getUser_id());

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (input.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Please enter some texts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Messages -- BEFORE 2 *******************************" + messagesCount);

                 myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                         .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                        .child("Chat")
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        );
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Messages AFTER 1 --- *******************************" + messagesCount);

                myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
                        .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child("Chat")
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        );
                myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
                        .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .child("ChatSettings")
                        .child("new_message_n")
                        .setValue(true);

                myConnectionsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        try{
                            notifMcount = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: NOTIFICATION COUNT MESSAGES--------------------- = " + notifMcount );
                            long newNotifAmount = notifMcount + 1;
                            myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                                    .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                                    .child("n_newmessages_c")
                                    .setValue(newNotifAmount);

                        }catch (NullPointerException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: NullPointerException" + e.getMessage() );
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                long newNotifAmount = notifMcount + 1;
                myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                        .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                        .child("n_newmessages_c")
                        .setValue(newNotifAmount);



                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Messages AFTER 2 --- *******************************" + messagesCount);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showAllOldMessages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in failed, please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void showAllOldMessages() {
    loggedInUserName = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Log.d("Main", "user id: " + loggedInUserName);

    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.item_in_message,
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .child(mUser.getUser_id())
                    .child("Chat"));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private User getUserFromBundle(){
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle != null){
        return bundle.getParcelable(getString(R.string.intent_user));
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(mUser.getUser_id())
            .child("ChatSettings")
            .child("new_message_n")
            .setValue(false);

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    myRef.child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(mUser.getUser_id())
            .child("ChatSettings")
            .child("new_message_n")
            .setValue(false);

}
```

Error message:

```
12-02 18:04:39.200 19657-19657/com.example.user.someapp E/MessengerMessagesFragme: getFollowing: searching for FRIENDS **************************************
12-02 18:04:40.106 3829-530/? E/ctxmgr: [AppIntervalImpl]closeInterval: ongoing
12-02 18:04:41.046 1472-1561/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
12-02 18:04:49.056 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
12-02 18:05:00.002 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
12-02 18:05:06.403 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
12-02 18:05:06.419 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
12-02 18:05:09.294 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
12-02 18:05:09.298 1472-1489/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
12-02 18:05:11.297 19657-19657/com.example.user.someapp E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
12-02 18:05:11.408 19657-19657/com.example.user.someapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.user.someapp, PID: 19657
                                                                                    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzb(Unknown Source:180)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zza(Unknown Source:312)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzb(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekq.zze(Unknown Source:153)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zzb(Unknown Source:772)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzekp.zza(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                                        at com.example.user.someapp.MessengerFriendsOnline$2.onDataChange(MessengerFriendsOnline.java:146)
                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source:7)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeex.zza(Unknown Source:13)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegs.zzbwg(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegy.run(Unknown Source:65)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Don't assume things are bugs. Search for your error. There's multiple suggestions for solutions. All relate to code you've written

Comment: I know i should, but its been a couple of frustrating days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is the correct way to get a Long from a DataSnapshot

```
notifMcount = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class)
```

Secondly, your User class has a wrong data type

```
mUserList.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
```

Something is a String, but actually an int in Firebase. Look at your code, and compare the string fields to the values without quotes in Firebase